# Populating JQuery DataTable In MVC SPA

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to populate a JQuery DataTable with data from my Controller.  Below is my JQuery and cshtml...what am I missing here?

```
<div id="table1">
    <table id="example" class="display">
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Pre API Checks</h1>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="btnTapCountCheck">TC Check</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#btnTapCountCheck").click(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("GTC", "TC")',
            method: "GET"
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "Location" },
            { data: "TC" }
        ]
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
On the button click event I get this error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (site.js?v=z24mdPOuYS…NZryPIzfHbE3qOQ2M:6)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)
(anonymous)    @    site.js?v=z24mdPOuYS…NZryPIzfHbE3qOQ2M:6
dispatch    @    jquery.js:5183
elemData.handle    @    jquery.js:4991
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml I have these two references added.

```
<head>
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @devlincarnate- see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code can't find the js for the Datatables. Try changing your references for the DataTables.

Try replacing your `head` tag to:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
```

and your `script` tags (usually near the bottom of your html) to:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Without seeing your full code it will be hard for me to fully test anything out but replace those tags and see if you receive that same error.

Comment: What full code can I provide?  What do you need to see?  In my _Layout.cshtml if I remove my code and replace with the 5 you provide...I get the error below on all lines....
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:44328/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
localhost/:15

Comment: Ah, ok. There's a mismatch of your code and the tag links using `http` and `https`. I've updated my tags. Try them now and see if you get any errors returned

Comment: I changed the links to `https` but if you change your local api url link to `http` that should also clear up that error as well without changing the datatable links to `https`

Comment: Changing the tags to your update, I get the same error in the Dev Console as before. --- I added the Tags in my _Layout.cshtml, and I have the JQuery in the site.js file, and I have the HTML in my index.cshtml

Comment: Did you add them in your _Element.cshtml? That's the only file I'm aware of. I don't see anything about a _Layout.cshtml file.

Comment: I don't have an _Element.cshtml, I only have a _Layout.cshtml....this is a pastebin of the file contents...I'm using ASP.Net Core & MVC   https://pastebin.com/iw8uA2Rf  ----- And this is what my project window looks like https://ibb.co/0VQvXZD

Comment: I'm confused now. In your question you stated "And in my _Element.cshtml I have these two references added." I also noticed in your 2 refernces that your don't have `http` nor `https` at the start of either link. If that's how you have all your links set up, I will update my answer,  and you try to add those links in your code and see what returns.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo....I only have a _Layout.cshtml.  I added an image and a pastebin.  Does that help?

Comment: Not really, the paste bin just looks like a generic regular pastbin page. Also have you tried replacing the links with my updated answer?

Comment: Yes - I replaced the links with your updated answer.